# How to solve error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I want to dynamically grab the ip adress from this device (since it changes overtime) and then fetch the JSON from the database by using a link in fetch: `https://{ipadress}:5000/users` from node.js server. But now it gives me an error  `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`. I don't know how to solve it.
The function `publicIP()` is where the problem is at.

```
async componentDidMount() {
            this.drawOnCanvas();
            var ipAdress = '';
            publicIP()
            .then(ip => {    
                console.log(ip);
                const url = "http://" + ip + ":5000/user";
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const data = await response.json(); 
                this.setState({userData: data});
                console.log(this.state.userData);
            // '47.122.71.234'
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            // 'Unable to get IP address.'
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.drawOnCanvas();
    try
    {
        var ip = await publicIP();
        console.log(ip);

        const url = "http://" + ip + ":5000/user";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json(); 
        this.setState({userData: data});
        console.log(this.state.userData);  // '47.122.71.234'
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);  // 'Unable to get IP address.'
    }
}
```

And additionally I think you should use either `async`/`await` OR `.then`/`.catch` but don't mix them.

Comment: Thanks! it worked. For some reason i get the wrong ip though, its different from when i type in command prompt ipconfig and go to ipv4. Any ideas to get the correct IP? So i can fetch it

Comment: It seems that you want to call an endpoint on your local machine, right? So why can't you just use the fixed value `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as your `ip`?

Comment: Well, I want to connect to this app from other computers as well.  Because of that I need the local ip of the computer where i run the react app on. So that other computers can also fetch the json data

Comment: OK but how should the other computers know the ip address of your host that is running your react app? I think you have to hard code the address in your consumers or do some routing (like editing `hosts` config to map an ip address to a dns name).

Comment: And as far as I know React is just a client side technology. So you starting a local server on the machine which wants to use this frontend. This server just serves the JS and HTML files for the frontend. There is no backend service involved here. If you want to call a backend to fetch some data you need a backend technology as well (NodeJS, Java, ...).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't mix `async/await` with `.then().catch()`. Select the one you like better and stick with it. So in your case You should either do

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.drawOnCanvas();
  var ipAdress = '';
  return publicIP()
    .then(ip => {    
      console.log(ip);
      const url = "http://" + ip + ":5000/user";
      return fetch(url);
    })
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({userData: data});
      console.log(this.state.userData);            
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
    });
}
```

or

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    this.drawOnCanvas();
    var ipAdress = '';
    const ip = await publicIP()
    console.log(ip);
    const url = "http://" + ip + ":5000/user";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json(); 
    this.setState({userData: data});
    console.log(this.state.userData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the first code example, is the `return` before `publicIP()` needed?!

Comment: @Yousaf Depends. In case of a react `componentDidMount()` probably not (I'm not very familiar with react, so I may be wrong here). In general case if you want some method `xy()` to be part of a promise chain, yes, because otherwise this won't wait for the promise to resolve/reject

Comment: `componentDidMount` is a lifecycle method, that `return` is not needed here.